# How to update a file with data in a loop in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, fs

I have a data which comes in a loop and I need to append the data to a file at position, but when I loop, the first record is only getting appended. I am not sure what the problem is.

My code,

```
for (i=0;i< data.length ;i++) {
    var file = fs.openSync(listBlogsFile, 'r+');
    var bufferedText = new Buffer(data[i] + modListData);
    fs.writeSync(file, bufferedText, 0, bufferedText.length, position);
}
```

Comment: Have you done console logging to find out where the issue is? I'd start by doing `console.log(data.length);` to check how many elements are actually in the array, and then `console.log(data[i] + modListData);` to check what data is being appended.

Comment: It looks like you're writing to the same position each time? In that case, I would expect only the *last* record to end up in the file.

Comment: ^ I was about to say that, it looks like your `position` variable doesn't change.

Comment: And opening file each iteration is not the best practice. Move the file opening outside of loop

Comment: I would recommend you to try to use WriteStream: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options and avoid *Sync calls to increase performace